# Android Studio not Starting

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, jetbrains-toolbox

I reinstalled android studio with the JetBrains toolbox and now android studio won't start.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.intellij.ide.plugins.IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl[] com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.loadDescriptors()'
        at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:121)
        at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:71)
        at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:19)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:303)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:245)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:47)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
2021-04-22 13:43:50,499 [    478]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio 4.1.3  Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.7199119
2021-04-22 13:43:50,501 [    480]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 14.0.1; VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation
2021-04-22 13:43:50,504 [    483]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Windows 10

Start Failed: Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.intellij.ide.plugins.IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl[] com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.loadDescriptors()'
        at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:121)
        at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:71)
        at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:19)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:303)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:245)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:47)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

-----
JRE 14.0.1+7 amd64 by Oracle Corporation
```

This is the error I am getting when I run the studio.bat file.

I have tried completely uninstalling the program and deleting all of the system files
I have checked if the system variables are proper locations
I have also renamed my `%AppData%\Roaming\Google\marketplace` folder to `%AppData%\Roaming\Google\marketplace_back`

Comment: Probably a broken plugin, Try removing "plugins" folder from the configuration folder: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config

Comment: I tried that and it did not work, Thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all my JetBrains folders and android studio folders then used CCleaner to clean my registry then reinstalled it without importing settings and it is working now